# Compare name of files to a column in a table and if a correspondence is found rename it according to another column

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, rename, csv, mv

I have an extensive set of files in a directory (in bash) that are named (inconveniently) as follows:

```
COMMONSTUFF_X_Y_**VARIABLE-IDENTIFIER**_COMMONSTUFF
```

I also have a table in which one column contains the `VARIABLE-IDENTIFIER` (note, not the full name, only the variable identifier part) and in another column there is a simple unique name (associated on the same row) which I would like to replace to the complex name which is unhandy, to the files in the directory.

I guess I could have a script that reads the name of the file, check if it has a correspondence with the variable identifier in a specific column of a table and if this is true, read the name that I need from another column and rename that file with this name.

I am new to shell scripting so I don't know where to start but I think this is doable.

Comment: What would that table look like?

Comment: It is a tab separated value file saved as .summary. Every row corresponds to one of the file of the directory and contains different info, one per column. One of these columns is the identifier part and another is the simple name I would like to substitute

Comment: Please consider adding samples of your files. It will help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it thusly, in `awk`:

```
awk -F, '{system("mv COMMONSTUFF_X_Y_" $1 "_COMMONSTUFF " $2)}' mycsv.csv
```

where 1 is the (1-indexed) column number of the VARIABLE-IDENTIFIER, and 2 is the number of the column of the simple unique name.